# Communicating state from the backend to the frontend while the user is logged in

Tags: architecture, web-development, event-programming, websockets, backend

**Please note:** although this question *mentions* Angular and Spring Boot (Java), and it would be *great* to get an answer from someone with experience in that stack, I think this is more of an architectural question at heart and certainly doesn't require Angular or Java/Spring experience to answer it.

---

So, I am designing out a web app that I would like to consist of the following architecture:

[image]

So:

- frontend web app (Angular) talks to a single RESTful backend web service (Java/Spring Boot)
- the backing web service itself talks to many other smaller services, databases, etc.
- the frontend web app serves up the UI and does all normal frontend stuff
- backend service houses business logic and other stuff that I don't want exposed to the frontend and ultimately browswer

In designing this out a scenario occurred to me that I can't figure out a good solution for, and wasn't sure what the generally-accepted options/solutions for it are.

Here is the scenario:

1. A user is logged into the app and has their browser pointed to, say, `https://myapp.example.com/fizz/buzz`
2. An admin of the app decides they want to suspend the user for 30 days and does so through an admin web app (or by running a script, whatever). When suspended, users can log in but should be redirected to a "You've been suspended!" splash page, and should not be able to navigate anywhere else inside the app. Only when the suspension is lifted should they be able to resume using the app

The problem here is, unless the frontend web app makes a call to the backend web service on each and every page load/reload, and on each and every AJAX/asynchronous call from the browser that warrants the application doing anything meaningful, there is no way for the frontend web app to "*know*" that the user has been banned and to implement the correct redirection (to the suspension page mentioned above).

Obviously, if this happens while the user is logged out, it would be easy to have the web app to call the `GET user/state` endpoint upon next login and determine if they are suspended or not. But if we want to have this suspension take effect while they are using the app, I'd have to add a call to that endpoint *everywhere* and that is nasty and smells.

**So what are the common solution(s) here?** How does the backend web service communicate changed state to a specific user logged in to the frontend web app? Websockets come to mind, but not sure if thats the right tool for the job as I have no concrete experience with them and am not sure if they apply for web service -> web app communication or just web app -> browser communication.

Thanks in advance for any and all help here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your architecture is missing a critical piece of identity management/authentication platform.

In applications that involve users with different roles/access controls, the architecture has a dedicated system for user management.

**Authentication** is the process of validating the that user is genuine (using a password/token). Think of it like someone checking you have tickets to enter a concert.

**Authorization** is checking that a user can actually access a resource that is protected by the identity management system. Think of it like someone checking if your ticket to the concert includes free drinks/food.

Most identity management systems incorporate both of the above. The two standards used for authentication and authorization are OIDC (Open ID Connect) and OAuth 2.0. Several identity management systems like keycloak and Auth0 already have implementations of such standards in their system.

[image: Diagram showing a OAuth 2.0 flow]

The identity management system is what is first hit when a user makes a request. This usually then redirects the user to authenticate by providing credentials. Once the credentials are authenticated, a token (JWT - JSON Web Token - pronounced 'Jot', with encrypted data using public/private key) with the user's roles/claims are issued to the user (to be stored in browser cookies, though not necessary).

This token is then passed/accessed with every request. Any route that is hit, should check the users roles/authorization which is usually in the token (JWT).

This validation has to be done by your API.
This is usually done by validating the roles for any user and seeing if that role is allowed to access the resource (usually this is done by some authentication middleware, which is common to all the routes - and that doesn't mean duplicated code in each route, just a common framework that checks the authorization is valid).

Comment: Thanks @m_vemuri (+1) I appreciate this answer, but I am very much so aware of OAuth and authn/z schemes. I specifically omitted it from my question because my problem at hand (if you read it) has nothing to do with authn/z and it would have been adding unnecessary details.

Comment: The core question here is: how does the admin tool, that interacts with the backend web service and suspends a user, relay that information on to the frontend web app and, ultimately, the user/browser, **while** the user is logged in. So that the next action the user takes, that results with a call between the browser and the web app, triggers the web app to redirect them to the suspension page. I would be _shocked_ if authentication can be used as a solution here. If it can, then by all means, please educate me and make the necessary changes to your question!

Comment: Your suggestion above would have the webapp asking the web service for the user's status (active/valid vs suspended) on every single user action in the browser (well, that requires a request to fire off), and that is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Also, the token might be valid for several more minutes, hours, etc. whereas the user needs to be suspended **now**!

Comment: While a token can be valid for several minutes, you can ask the auth server to invalidate any previously issued tokens. That will trigger the auth server to generate a new token upon a new request/authentication. 

The point of the auth server is that the applications routes do not actually perform user authentication, it is a redirection to the auth server which then comes back with a 401 if unauthorized. 

If you have an auth server, your application should authenticate every request to your backend. If you don't, you have a security hole that is an open vulnerability.

Comment: Then anytime I suspend a user, I would have to tell the server to invalidate all my users' tokens and it would force everyone to log back into the app. Sorry but I really feel like auth is not the right way to go here.

Comment: You don't invalidate all user tokens. You only invalidate the token for one user. Every user has their own token. If you are sharing tokens across users, that is bad security practice and is opening you to man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: No but then you need to keep a list somewhere (DB?) of each user's specific token, no? And isn't that a performance anti-pattern, and the whole reason JWTs were invented? I'm honestly not trying to argue with you (!!) I'm just trying to see the forest through the trees here.

Comment: It's alright even if you're arguing. I'm just trying to understand it better so I can provide a better answer (if needed) :) . The point of an auth server is to avoid having user information in the application database. The auth server handles authentication/authorization for you. You shouldn't store token's in your database (which again opens you to vulnerabilities - an injection attack can get the tokens).

Comment: I re-read your question. I maybe misunderstanding your situation. It sounds like you want the screen/front-end to show the "You've been suspended!" splash page without contacting the backend. 
If that's the case, your websocket approach can work. You'd have to communicate with the server from the admin tool to terminate the websocket. Your front end should be written in a reactive style, which updates based on the changes to the websocket.

Comment: Thanks, correct: I want the backend to notify (event-driven like) the webapp that the user has been suspended, so that the next time the browser makes any request to the webapp, the webapp knows to redirect them to the suspension page.

Comment: If you want an immediate solution, yes websockets . If you dont mind the user clicking a few more times before they are notified then authorization(not authentication) is the solution .